# Getting error Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list with special characters

Tags: javascript, html

Getting an error message when try to call a javascript onkeyup function.Please let me know how can i solve this

```
<input type="text" name="dt" onkeyup="test('345*$kl&#39;g%-?$^gh546tyu*$5670&/>*$gd&#39;4563')" />


function test(kw) {
  var arr = kw.split("*$");
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    console.log("dt=" + arr[i]);
}
```

want to split the string based on '*$'

Comment: Are you sure you've posted all the relevant code? The snippet you posted is not a properly formatted for-loop.

Comment: pls check if you've lost something in your code and format it.

Comment: No missing of )  bracket at the end of function calling.please check

Comment: @amazonic — The for loop is properly formatted. It is perfectly fine to follow `for()` with a single statement instead of a block.

Comment: @Suvankar — The `)` is missing because the end of the function call isn't where you think it is.

Comment: @Quentin It wasn't when i commented, though.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you're missing some stuff while calling the function in your HTML ! Your HTML should be formatted like this:

```
<input type="text" name="dt" onkeyup='test("345*$kl&#39;g%-?$^gh546tyu*$5670&*$gd&#39;4563")' />
```

Cheers!

Comment: but you removed two chars from the string. `/` and `>` which is basically the problem here.

Comment: yes,he remove two characters,after removing this two character still it is not working.

Comment: hey @Suvankar I updated my code we need to use `""` inside the parameter passing and `''` outside the function calling. Try now it works

Answer (score 1):

You are nesting JavaScript inside HTML and are escaping a character for HTML instead of for JavaScript.

Inside an HMTL attribute delimited with `"`, you need to escape `"` characters as `&quot;`.

Inside a JavaScript string delimited with `'`, you need to escape the `'` characters as `\'`.

```
onkeyup="test('345*$kl&#39;g%-?$^gh546tyu*$5670&/>*$gd&#39;4563')"
                      ▲▲▲▲                            ▲▲▲▲
```

Here you have escaped `'` as `#39;` so the HTML parser converts them to `'` and then sends:

```
test('345*$kl'g%-?$^gh546tyu*$5670&/>*$gd'4563')
```

… to the JavaScript parser … which ends the string literal early.

Change it to:

```
onkeyup="test('345*$kl\'g%-?$^gh546tyu*$5670&/>*$gd\'4563')"
```

---

Better yet, don't embed JavaScript in HTML in the first place.

You could do something like this instead:

```js
function test(event) {
  var kw = event.currentTarget.dataset.string;
  var arr = kw.split("*$");
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    console.log("dt=" + arr[i]);
}

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', test)
```

```html
<input type="text" name="dt" data-string="345*$kl&#39;g%-?$^gh546tyu*$5670&/>*$gd&#39;4563">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes '' outside and double quotes "" inside for your test method call ,

what was happening with your code is, `345*$kl&#39;g%-$^gh546tyu*$5670&/>*$gd&#39;4563` in your string you have used `/>`, so its getting considered as closing tag for onkeyup method call.

```
 <input type='text' name='dt' onkeyup='test("345*$kl&#39;g%-$^gh546tyu*$5670&/>*$gd&#39;4563")' />

function test(kw) {
var arr = kw.split("*$");
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
console.log("dt=" + arr[i]);
}
```

after running I got this output in my console

`dt=345
dt=kl'g%-?$^gh546tyu
dt=5670&/>
dt=gd'4563`

Answer (score -1):

You are using a fixed string inside the Javascript function so you can insert the string directly inside the Javascript function itself. Probably you don't want this but you are trying to parse the input inserted by the user. I mean, something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="dt" onkeyup="test()">


<script>
function test() {
  var x = document.getElementById("dt");
  var arr = x.value.split("*$");
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
   console.log("dt=" + arr[i]);
}
</script>
```